# Very slow calculation in FlatList React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good day! Faced with a problem, I get an array of data from the database. In the data:
1.Name
2.
I output it all to the FlatList
and add small buttons - +
, i.e. I want to increase and decrease each value
, but the operations are very slow, it takes more than 1 second

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, StyleSheet, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { getStopList } from '../../functions/1c/getMenu';

const StopList = () => {
  const [stopListData, setStopListData] = useState([]);
  const [isFetching, setisFetching] = useState(false);

  const onRefresh = () => {
    setisFetching(true);
    fetchData().then(() => {
      setisFetching(false); // Сбросить состояние после загрузки данных
      ToastAndroid.show("Данные обновлены!", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    });
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await getStopList();
    setStopListData(data.Данные);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, [])
  );

  const handleIncrement = (itemId) => {
    const updatedData = stopListData.map((entry) =>
      entry.id === itemId
        ? { ...entry, Остаток: (parseInt(entry.Остаток) + 1).toString() }
        : entry
    );
    setStopListData(updatedData);
  };
  
  const handleDecrement = (itemId) => {
    const updatedData = stopListData.map((entry) =>
      entry.id === itemId && parseInt(entry.Остаток) > 0
        ? { ...entry, Остаток: (parseInt(entry.Остаток) - 1).toString() }
        : entry
    );
    setStopListData(updatedData);
  };
  
  const MyItemComponent = React.memo(({ item, onPressDecrement, onPressIncrement }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.Товар}</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressDecrement} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>—</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={[styles.counterText, { minWidth: 50, textAlign: 'center', color: '#FF9A00', fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>{item.Остаток}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressIncrement} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  });

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <MyItemComponent
      item={item}
      onPressDecrement={() => handleDecrement(item.id)}
      onPressIncrement={() => handleIncrement(item.id)}
    />
  );

  const keyExtractor = useCallback((item) => item.id.toString(), []);

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#323232", flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        extraData={stopListData}
        data={stopListData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        initialNumToRender={15}
        onRefresh={onRefresh} 
        refreshing={isFetching} 
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I tried using memo but it didn't help, maybe I have the wrong approach at all.
the meaning is that I want to display a list of each element has a value and a button - or + I want to decrease or add the value by 1

Comment: On the first view this doesn't look super wrong. I would recommend to have the `MyItemComponent` defined outside of the rendering of the list. Same for the keyExtractor.

You can then use `useCallback` for the handeIncrement / hanldeDecrement functions.

You can remove the extraData prop, I guess.

Is your list very long for some reason? I mean you're going through the entire list every button press, if that has lots of entries that for sure will be taking some time.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your comment and tested a bit.
As I stated in my comment already. The most important thing here is to extract the item component and have it outside of the list component. In your code the component gets recreated all over and only then rendered. That probably causes the List to rerender all of its children every time.

I created a small Expo snack where I did that and then it runs quite smoothly on my device.

https://snack.expo.dev/@baumstumpf/stackoverflow-flatlistperformance

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then it should have been done like this:
[link](https://pastebin.com/Dyjbs6Dx)
But it didn't help me. I apologize in advance, maybe I didn't understand something, I'm a beginner